# Improper method declaration or method repetition?

Tags: java

```
private int repetition;

  public int repetition(int sum){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers greater than 0: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++){

      System.out.println("Please enter number: ");
      number[i] = sc.nextInt();

      if (number[i] < 0){
        System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 0");
        i--;
        sum -= number[i];
      }
      sum += number[i];
    }
    return int sum;
  }
  repetition(sum);
}
```

I am getting an error that says that I have an invalid method declaration but I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: On which line ? and give definition of `number[]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: What do you think that last `repetition(sum)` is supposed to do? And `return int sum;`?

Comment: You're calling `repitition(sum)` outside of the method.

Comment: this is also wrong `return int sum;`

Comment: why are you passing a parameter to `repetition` ? - you never use it's value

Answer (score 0):

Please read the above comments

I have modified your code so that it works, and added comments inline

```
// you need a `main` as the entry point to your program
public static void main(String... args) {
    // my class is called `Main` so I instantiate it and call your method
    System.out.println("the sum is " + new Main ().repetition());

}

// no parameters necessary
public int repetition(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // keep a sum
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers greater than 0: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){  // loop five times

      System.out.println("Please enter number: ");
      // store into a local variable
      int in = sc.nextInt();

      // if less than zero then goto the top of the loop again
      if (in < 0){
        System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 0");
        i--;
        continue;
      }

      // else add it to the sum
      sum += in;
    }

    // finally return the sum
    return sum;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Second to last line. Your method call is outside of any method.